# Getting past a SAML login screen with Cypress

Tags: javascript, authentication, saml, cypress

I am new to Cypress, and test automation in general, but we have decided to use this tool for some basic e2e testing and post deploy sanity checks, specifically on our webpages with Looker dashboards integrated.  Looks like great software but I am having a problem getting through our SAML Authentication...the Cypress documentation describes a few solutions but I can't seem to figure out why my code is not completing successfully. Here is what I have:

```
describe('Main page', function() {
  it('login page should render', function() {
    cy.visit('/login/email')
    cy.get('#login-email')
      .should('be.visible')
  })
  it('uses the login fields', function() {
    cy.get('#login-email').type('user@supercool.com')
    cy.get('#login-password').type('password')
      .should('have.value', 'password')
    cy.get('#login-submit').click()
  })
  it('redirects to dashboard after login', function() {
    cy.visit('/dashboards/analytics_external::live_event_summary?time_filter=6%20months&title_filter=&filter_config=%7B"time_filter":%5B%7B"type":"past","values":%5B%7B"constant":"6","unit":"mo"%7D,%7B%7D%5D,"id":4%7D%5D,"title_filter":%5B%7B"type":"%3D","values":%5B%7B"constant":""%7D,%7B%7D%5D,"id":5%7D%5D%7D')
    cy.url().should('include', 'dashboards')
  })
})
```

Right now, it works right up until the user/pass are submitted.  I get this Uncaught Error: [$injectort:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Looker due to: Error:[$injector:nomod] Module 'Looker' is not available! https://screencast.com/t/52EnQuYgVL

I know this is very basic so thank you ahead of time for the patience, and understanding.  I have combed through pretty much everything related to login, and read through all the Cypress docs but I'm just missing something here so any insight is much appreciated! THANKS!